# Codeigniter form will not save content with a % percentage sign

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter-3

I have a basic form running in codeigniter 3 which saves some content from a simple textarea field.

If I attempt to save content with the following inside 'this needs to be 99% accurate', on post, it converts it to 'this needs to be 99�curate', causing the content to not save within my REST API.

Is there a setting in config that I need to update?

Comment: Welcome to SO. There is not much info here for anyone to be able to help.  How are you saving your data? Where are you saving it to - a database? What database? "*causing the content to not save within my REST API*" - wait, if it isn't saving, where is that funny character showing up? Please edit your question, add some details - copy-paste errors if you are getting any.  Take a minute to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: BTW I searched for "*codeigniter mysql percentage sign*" and found some suggestions; "*codeigniter mysql strange character*" turned up plenty more. Did you try all those already?  Eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091819/mysql-and-php-function-not-displaying-percentage-sign-correctly, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20758130/php-mysql-codeigniter-converting-characters-to-symbols-in-very-bizarre-circumsta, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237474/strange-character-encoding-of-stored-data-old-script-is-showing-them-fine-new ...

Comment: also setting something like `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`in your html view might help

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.